не могу установить библиотеку для python asyncpg
У меня проблема не могу установить библиотеку для пайтона asyncpg, пытался обновить pip ничего не получается.
asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(864): warning C4996: 'Py_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.13
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(865): warning C4996: 'Py_UNICODE': deprecated in 3.13
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(1667): warning C4013: _PyInterpreterState_GetConfig: ­Ґв ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп; ЇаҐ¤Ї®« Ј Ґвбп "extern" б ў®§ўа в®¬ вЁЇ  "int"
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(1667): error C2223: ўла ¦Ґ­ЁҐ б«Ґў  ®в "->optimization_level" ¤®«¦­® гЄ §лў вм ­  бвагЄвгаг Ё«Ё ®ЎкҐ¤Ё­Ґ­ЁҐ
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(38932): warning C4013: _PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters: ­Ґв ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп; ЇаҐ¤Ї®« Ј Ґвбп "extern" б ў®§ўа в®¬ вЁЇ  "int"
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(41809): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(42043): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(42239): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(42435): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(42745): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(43055): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(43289): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(43485): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(43719): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c(43915): error C2198: int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject *,unsigned char *,size_t,int,int,int): б«ЁиЄ®¬ ¬ «®  аЈг¬Ґ­в®ў ¤«п ўл§®ў
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for asyncpg
Failed to build asyncpg
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (asyncpg)

вот что в конце выдает. Там вот шло нормально все потом после определенного момента проблема с кодировкой пошла и не разбериха

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

просто не могу установить библиотеку и выходит вот такая ошибка которую я указал, версию пайтон которую я использую 3.13

Во-первых, читайте полный текст ошибки, а не самые бесполезные его строчки. Во-вторых, используйте питон 3.12

@andreymal обновил ошибку

Почитал про библиотеку и она поддерживает максимум 3.12 версию пайтона. Поэтому поставте версию 3.12 и я думаю всё установится

@RSK спасибо помогло, установил версию 3.12.6 помогло
